# Load image and have it ready when button is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying make an improvement to my code by using an XML as my 'database' making it easy to add remove images.

before the way I was doing it was import the image then add it to a movieclip that was exported for action script then when a button was clicked find that movieclip and add it to stage to be used.

I'm trying to keep this as similar as possible for the new XML way.

I can import my XML and then find the image and have it ready using this:

```
    function importXML(){
        var loadXML:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loadXML.load(new URLRequest("../xml/images.xml"));
        loadXML.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    }


    function processXML(e:Event):void{
        imageXML = new XML(e.target.data);
        var image   = imageXML.image.(@name=="image1").image;
        trace(image);
        importImage(image);
    }


   function importImage(imageName:String) {
        var loadIMG = new Loader();
        var url     = "../images/last_steps/"+imageName;
        var url_req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        loadIMG.load(url_req);
        loadIMG.name = "image1";

    }
```

Now im tried giving it a name so that the function that runs on click would work:

```
    function myButtonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        addImage("image1");
    }

    function addImage(image:String)
    {
        var imageName = image;
        var imageClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(imageName) as Class;

         addChild(imageClass);
    }
```

The last function would work when I did it manually adding it into a movieClip but it does not work now I have tried this as well:

```
    function addImage(image:String)
    {
        var imageName = image;
        // var imageClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(imageName) as Class;

        addChild(imageName);
    }
```

This does not work as well.

To summarise my question is how can I link the image imported via XML to the name when clicking of a button?

Comment: function myButtonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        addImage("image1"); this is wring as the event inniated before the image is loaded

Comment: Will there be one button created per image in your xml ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is briefly onComplete function() add event listener to the button instance, then you can addChild, picture would be ready always at this time on this condition

Comment: So there is no way to just sorta set 'the image name' then pass that in on click which can be found by something like 'getChildByName()' ?

Comment: your looking at it wrong, sorry...lol everything  is a basic form to a point, so if you want the image a name you give it one, when you load the image in flash, you gave the loader that  ,,,,name" my loader" you define what you want manipulate how you like.

Comment: get child be name will be predifined , either by youself or flash

Comment: @jushua How am i looking at it wrong? 1. Load image 2. Add to movie clip 3. give the movieclip a name 4. find that movieclip again and do what I want with it. This kinda thing must be possible as it can be done in many other programming languages. Maybe I just don't understand what you are saying as there seems to be a lot of bad english being used. Also if I'm going to ask for your help im going to do it in stack no your website.

Comment: fair enough, what you wrote above is correct, i thought you were implying something else, but you still need to have a complete function on the loader, to let it knows the picture is ready